# React Higher Order Components Function argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand the HOC example in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) when it comes to passing in the second argument, selectData. How is that function being passed and utilized,like just  general flow of what is happening with selectData?

```js
const CommentListWithSubscription = withSubscription(
  CommentList,
  (DataSource) => DataSource.getComments()
);
```

```js
// This function takes a component...
function withSubscription(WrappedComponent, selectData) {
  // ...and returns another component...
  return class extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          data: selectData(DataSource, props)
        };
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood. DataSource is a global.
Calling SelectData will trigger the callback provided by the arrow function ie DataSource.getComments().